# How to create custom rectangles as shown below programatically in objective-C using UIBezierPath or any other method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath

[image: First custom rectangle]

[image: Second custom rectangle]

How to create this custom UIImageview shapes like Rectangle 1, Rectangle 2 ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 UIBezierPath *aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    // Set the starting point of the shape.
    if (Flag==0) {
//First rectangle

        [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(0.0, 0.0)];
        // Draw the lines.

        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(375.0, 0.0)];

        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(367.5, 32.8)];

        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(7.5, 32.8)];

           } else {
//Second Rectangle

        [aPath moveToPoint:CGPointMake(7.5, 0.0)];

        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(367.5, 0.0)];

        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(375, 32.8)];

        [aPath addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(0, 32.8)];

    }

    [aPath closePath];

    return aPath;
```